# Privacy of "Hey, Siri" on Apple Watch

Tags: siri, apple-watch, privacy, watchos

I recently got an Apple Watch Series 2 and discovered the "Hey, Siri" feature, where you can talk to Siri hands-free after raising your wrist. I know Apple made very clear statements about the privacy of "Hey, Siri" on iPhone - no recording is sent anywhere until AFTER you have said "Hey, Siri". I couldn't find equally clear statements about the privacy of this feature on Apple Watch.

I am wondering if Apple Watch sends an audio recording to the Apple servers every time I raise my wrist. Does anyone know of any official statement from Apple about this?

Comment: Since “Hey, Siri” on your iPhone is always listening, yet doesn’t send any data to Apple until it detects the magic phrase, my guess would be that it works the same way on WATCH. This would be especially true considering Siri on the watch passes through your iPhone.

The only situation I could see this behaving differently is if you’re using your WATCH on Wi-Fi untethered from your iPhone.

Comment: @Phong I would guess the same, but what's interesting is that "Hey, Siri" on the Watch works even tough I never taught it the phrase on my iPhone, which makes me think that the Apple Servers might be involved